# Прошу оценить вёрстку

Tags: html

Прошу вас оценить вёрстку.

Интересует, правильно ли сделан адаптив, что можно улучшить в нём/изменить/добавить...  Насколько верно сделана логика блока с тестом(с чистым js работал 1-ый раз, до этого jQuery), можно ли как-то минимизировать, сделать проще и т.д.  Если есть замечания по другим частям работы,  пишите,  в следующий раз буду внимательнее=). Возможно ли с таким уровнем выполнять несложные заказы?/брать на доработку отдельные блоки...

[Ссылка на вёрстку](http://Vlad-Vasinev.github.io)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Несколько замечаний после беглого просмотра:

1. Вёрстка неадаптивная. В эпоху господства мобильных устройств учитесь сразу верстать под любые размеры экранов. Вообще в идеале использовать принцип mobile first. Посмотрите в сторону фреймворков типа Bootstrap, изучите, как там устроена сетка. Это поможет в принципе понять, как лучше делать раскладку страницы.
2. Не используйте в разметке устаревшие атрибуты - align, valign и т.д. Они, конечно, будут работать, но в html5 это считается дурным тоном. Применяйте магию css.
3. Меню в виде таблицы - это не айс. Опять же посмотрите, как делаются менюшки в Бутстрапе. И в принципе таблицы в вёрстке лучше использовать лишь тогда, когда требуется собственно таблица. Для всех остальных случаев есть другие элементы.
4. Применяйте теги html5: header, footer, main, nav, section, aside и т.д. Только сперва изучите, как их грамотно использовать :)
5. Не забывайте про обязательные атрибуты: например, в img должен быть alt="" (пустой или с каким-то замещающим текстом). Это важно для валидности вёрстки.
6. Названия классов - дело, во многом, субъективное, но ситуация, когда рядом идут `column-1` и `column1` - это откровенно плохо. В такой разметке легко запутаться и трудно её поддерживать.
7. Флексы использовать можно и нужно (хотя уже стоит смотреть в сторону гридов), но следует хорошо изучить их возможности и особенности.
8. Без сомнения, одни из самых крутых курсов по вёрстке - это htmlacademy (не реклама, если что, просто они реально топчег).

Comment: Спасибо,буду исправляться